# maven settings.xml file proxy setting for personal computer

Tags: spring, maven, proxy, settings, pom.xml

[image]

Please help me to get settings.xml file for personal computer.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't have any settings.xml for working from home without corporate firewall / proxy...Apart from that excluding google. and ibiblio for maven access is also wrong cause it will not being used by Maven..

Comment: Thanks a lot @khmarbaise ! Now I have removed the proxy and using only <proxies/> its working fine.